# Building a menu using css html

Tags: html, css

I need my menu to change color when hovering my mouse over each top menu. The problem is the background color for both Test1 and Sub test1 changes as I hover my mouse. Is there any way to not change the background color of Sub test1 until I hover the mouse over it? See the code at http://jsfiddle.net/r5YCU/22/

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
 <div id="navbar">
<ul>      
   <li class="navbutton"><span><a id="button-1" 
       href="">Shop</a></span>
   </li>
   <li class="navbutton"> <span><a href="#">Test1</a></span>
            <ul>
                <li><br/><span><a href="#">Sub test1</a>
                    </span>
                </li>
            </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="navbutton"><span><a id="button-3" 
       href="#">Test2</a>  
       </span>
   </li>
   <li class="navbutton"><span><a id="button-4" 
       href="#">Test3</a></span>
   </li>
   <li class="navbutton"><span><a id="button-5" 
       href="#">Test4</a></span>
   </li>
```

Comment: How come you're using jQuery to trigger hover states? You can just use CSS

Comment: The problem is the CSS background color is applied to the class `navbutton`. You need to use a pseudo selector or something to apply the style only to navbutton and none of its children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd play with css :hover pseudoclass instead javascript events, something like:

```
li.navbutton:hover {
    background-color:#345808 !important;
}
li.navbutton:hover li {
    background-color: #5c8727!important;
}
li.navbutton li:hover {
    background-color: #345808!important;
}
```

The complete code is: http://jsfiddle.net/r5YCU/31/

I've adapted the layout a bit to look as similar as possible to the original menu, but only with css code.

Comment: But it still does not accomplish what I initially asked. It is good to know I could do the hover states with CSS though.

Comment: @Tumen_t, Why not ? The children options appear with the light green color, don't they ?

Comment: No, it does not look quiet right. I want it to behave like the other menus. Changing the color as I hover over it.

Comment: Ok, but I think that the problem is not the background color, which It changes if you hover the mouse over them, but as I said in my answer, the layout needs some changes to remove the parent margins. It works in my browsers, what browser/version are you using ?

Comment: @Tumen_t, I've updated the code (http://jsfiddle.net/r5YCU/31/) in order to fix the layout issues, I've tested it in Chrome and Firefox (latests versions) and looks Ok for me, please, let me know if now It works as expected.

Comment: Is there any way I can reference the parent <li> as I hover the child <li>. I just want to change the back color of the top menu as I hover the sub menu. No biggie. It would be nice to have it working that way. Thanks

Comment: As far as I know you can not reference the parent with CSS, for that you can try your first approach using JS to add/remove a css class to the navbar element. But, if you can, I suggest you to use an existing library for manage that kind of components, just like Bootstrap or jQuery UI, you'll save a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

**These things are related to style and should be done in css...**

**CSS**

```
.ul{
    list-style: none;
}
#navbar a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
#main-ul{
    background: yellow;
}
.navmenu{
    float: left;
    background: deeppink;
    width: 60px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 3px black;
}
.navmenu:hover{
    outline: 1px solid white;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
.navmenu:hover > #sub-ul{
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;


}
#sub-ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
}
.submenu{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
.submenu:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    color: black;
    background: #585858;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div id="navbar">
      <ul class="ul" id="main-ul">      
         <li class="navmenu"><a href="#">Test1</a></li>
         <li class="navmenu"><a href="#">Test2</a>
              <ul class="ul" id="sub-ul">
                <li class="submenu">Test 1</li>
                <li class="submenu">Test 2</li>
                <li class="submenu">Test 3</li>
                <li class="submenu">Test 4</li>
                <li class="submenu">Test 5</li>
                <li class="submenu">Test 6</li>
                <li class="submenu">Test 7</li>
                <li class="submenu">Test 8</li>
              </ul>
         </li>
         <li class="navmenu"><a href="#">Test3</a></li>
         <li class="navmenu"><a href="#">Test4</a></li>
         <li class="navmenu"><a href="#">Test5</a></li>
         <li class="navmenu"><a href="#">Test6</a></li>
         <li class="navmenu"><a href="#">Test7</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```